# Get word in list variable with a other variable in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

Quick question: how to get particular word from list variable "randomly" in Power Automate?

I try: SendKeys: %Words[RandomText]%

Words is a list var with 1000 words, RandomText is a var with a random value (0 -> 999) but I have the error: The "Words" variable does not have a "6" property. 6 is the random value...

Thanks in advance

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAy3B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RandomNumber and not RandomText
RandomNumber create a value and RandomText create a string